# Spring Boot Jasper Integration

Tags: spring, maven, jasper-reports

I am trying to integrate Jasper into a Spring Boot project. I am using the following dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

As a test, the code below compiles without any errors:

```
Map params = new HashMap();
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(System.getProperty("jasper.reports.filepath") + "test.jrxml");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

But I am getting the following errors and not sure what or why it is happening:

[image]

And the lost goes on and on. As soon as I remove the jasper dependencies from the pom, all these errors are gone.

Any Help Please.

Comment: Did you add jaspersoft maven repository? Or did you install `net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports`, `net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts` artifactories at your maven repo (local or corporate)?

Comment: This is a local project I am working on, does it not automatically download it to my .m2 repo when adding it to the pom?

Comment: This jars maybe are absent at central repo. Usually I'm adding jaspersoft repo to work with latest and actual versions

Comment: Thanks, do you perhaps have a clean settings xml file I can use? Or where can I find one which will download the dependencies for me? I think mine might be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a maven clean build . These errors will be gone.

Happened to me too. Seems to be an Eclipse issue

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Jasper working example - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spring-boot-jasper-integration-prateek-ashtikar/.

This example includes the Spring Boot Jasper integration to create reports in PDF, XLXS, HTML and CSV.